# How character convert to integer number?

Tags: c++

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a;
   cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
   cin >> a;
   string a_str;
   ostringstream temp;
   temp << a;
   a_str = temp.str();

   for(int i = 0; i < a_str.length(); i++) {
      char c = a_str[i]; //How this character convert to integer number
   }

   system("pause");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How `char c` convert to `int` ?
I need this for
I need this because I need to get the highest digit

Comment: You mean that you have e.g. the character `'1'` and you want the integer `1`? Check an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and you might figure it out. Hint: It involves subtraction.

Comment: Char is in fact a kind of int (int8 or int16); so you can do the conversion like "int v = a_str[i] - '0';"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get char '8' to int 8 for example, this would be enough for ascii

```
int i = a_str[0] - '0';
```

Comment: Explicit would be: `int i = static_cast<int>(a_str[0]) - 48`

Answer (score 1):

```
const int i = atoi(&c);
```

should work too

Answer (score 0):

char is already an integral type. I think you meant the following

```
char c = a_str[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
atoi(c) for integers
atof(c) for floats
```

do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it yourself:
This works for normal keys (not arrows keys or...)

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

int main () {

```
char c;
cin >> c;
cout << (int)c << endl;
```

}

if you just have digits, you can do this:

```
int num = c - '0';
```